# Determine whether the set $S=\{(2a-b, 3b+a) : a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

(The space of all 2x2 matrices with real entities)

So, Am I right in saying that for it to be a subspace it needs to contain the zero vector, and be closed under addition and scalar multiplication?

If this is correct, how does one go about showing the above set is indeed  subspace of $M_2$ or not?

I appreciate any help, thanks for your time!

Comment: $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ isn't the set of all $2\times2$ matrix with real coefficients? and $S\subset\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are to follow the literal definition, then the answer is no: $S$ is not a subset of $M_2(\Bbb R)$ so it is certainly not a subspace of $M_2(\Bbb R)$.

However, $S$ may be identified with the set
$$
V=
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
2\,a-b & 0 \\
0 & a+3\,b
\end{bmatrix}
\in M_2(\Bbb R) :
a,b\in\Bbb R
\right\}
$$
which *is* a subspace of $M_2(\Bbb R)$. Identifications of this sort are sometimes useful, depending on the mathematical setting.

Of course, this identification of $S$ with $V$ is *non-cannonical*. The set $S$ can also be identified with 
$$
W=
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &2\,a-b  \\
0 & a+3\,b
\end{bmatrix}
\in M_2(\Bbb R) :
a,b\in\Bbb R
\right\}
$$
which is also a subspace of $M_2(\Bbb R)$.

So, in short, the answer to your question is "no" but I wouldn't get mad if you said yes, providing you provided a sensible identification.

Answer (score 2):

A subspace of a vector space $V$ is a subset of $V$ that has three properties you mentioned.
$S$ is not even a subset of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$. It fails from the very beginning.